# Software to easily create Wikivoyage banners

Tags: web-apps, image-processing, wikidata, wikimedia-commons, wikivoyage

[Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/New_York_City) volunteers need to create banners to place at the top of each article. Thousands of banners like this one:

[image: Wikivoyage banner]

Here is [the process](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wikivoyage:Banner_Expedition#How_to_make_a_quality_banner) for each locality in the world:

1. Example of locality: [New York City](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/New_York_City)
2. Click on the [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:New_York_City) link on the left
3. Filter out all images whose width is less than 2100 pixels
4. Select the greatest remaining picture
5. Select a 2100x300 area within that picture
6. Save it as a new picture
7. Upload that picture to Wikimedia Commons, with the same license as the original, and using [the {{Image extracted}} template](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Template:Image_extracted)
8. Set this picture as the [banner property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P948) of the [article's Wikidata item](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q60)

A webapp that would help with all of that would be wonderful.
At least, are there tools that can help with a few of the steps?

- The only steps where a human is needed are 4 and 5.
- At step 5, it would be great if the 2100x300 shape was enforced when selecting. Or even better, if the tool allowed a larger selection, but enforced the same ratio (banner must be 2100x300 or bigger with the same ratio)
- Extra bonus for the ability to rotate the picture before cropping
- The best is webapps, but I am OK with software for any operating system.

Comment: For 3-4 you can use [catscan](http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php), 5-7 is the [good old bug 7757](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T9757) but there's also [croptool](https://tools.wmflabs.org/croptool/).

Comment: @Nemo: Would a 7757 solution be usable in Wikidata? Croptool says "Internal error" :-/ A croptool-like solution that enforces the width/height ratio would be wonderful :-)

Comment: Wikidata would need to support it (in the interim it would be supported by a string-type qualifier), but first it needs to work in MediaWiki core. :) Pity for the error, are you sure you enabled cookies and everything and did you authenticate successfully? I've not used it recently, please [report](https://github.com/danmichaelo/croptool/issues/new)!

Comment: I reported already at https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Danmichaelo the operator is investigating right now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Banners can be cropped online using [CropTool](https://tools.wmflabs.org/croptool/) without editing them in an external picture editor. Another advantage is that most of the necessary file information (author, description, license) is added automatically.

- Open existing source the file in Commons
- Select CropTool from the Tools panel on the left
- (The first time, you have to authorize the tool)
- Select Aspect ratio: 7:1, press Preview
- Check the preview, select Upload as new file and type the new file name according to the above instructions
- Press Upload
- After successful upload, check the new file and add it to the appropriate category "Category:Wikivoyage banners of "